Vite is stripping @font-face from CSS Module when using inline
I am using CSS Modules with Vite.
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ClockFace';
    src: url('./assets/fonts/VictorMono-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('./assets/fonts/VictorMono-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('./assets/fonts/VictorMono-Regular.ttf') format('ttf');
}

When Vite generates the style.css for this file, it properly creates a Base64 representation of the font.
But, this is a library build and I don't want the consumer of this component to be responsible for importing style.css. So, I have used the ?inline option when importing the CSS. When I do this, Vite is stripping the @font-face directive from the CSS string.
I understand the desire to not load fonts per component instance, but I am taking care of that via my own CSS injection.
Is there an option to enable this?

Does the inline option create a <style> element or a style attribute?

Inline will generate a JS file that default exports the CSS as a string, suitable for putting inside of 
Probably not causing the issue but you should change format to truetype - ttf is not valid and may cause validation issues. Another guess: if this font-family is not specified anywhere else in subsequent css rules - vite may omit the @font-face during "tree-shaking".

The only two rules are the declaration of the font-face and the selector that uses it. It is not getting tree shaken.
